# I want to create a login with authentication in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

```
login(data: any) {
    this.user.getUsers().subscribe(
      (users) => {
        const user = users.find((u) => u.username === data.username && u.userpassword === data.password);

        if (user) {
          // Valid username and password, navigate to the dashboard
          this.route.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
          // Invalid username or password, handle accordingly (e.g., show an error message)
          console.error('Invalid username or password');
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I have this code, but in it, it shows subscriber is deprecated, and after clicking the login button, it does not open the dashboard page.

I want that when I add data that is present in a json file, only it will login and navigate to the dashboard page.

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error, we need to specify the function in subscribe in which block it needs to happen.

When you specify the next and error block in the old syntax as arguments, then you will get the deprecated error, instead go for an object, with properties specifying which function is for which event, there are three blocks

- `next` -> the observable has emitted a new value and can emit new values in the future
- `error` -> an error has occoured in the observable stream
- `complete` -> the observable has completed emitting values and will not emit new values in the future

code

```
login(data: any) {
    this.user.getUsers().subscribe({
      next:(users) => {
        const user = users.find((u) => u.username === data.username && u.userpassword === data.password);

        if (user) {
          // Valid username and password, navigate to the dashboard
          this.route.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
          // Invalid username or password, handle accordingly (e.g., show an error message)
          console.error('Invalid username or password');
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
      }
    });
  }
```